# What does "minute maid" mean?

Tags: expressions

I understand the meaning of both words, but I can't figure out what the expression means.

Comment: That was Tattoo's wife on Fantasy Island.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is only one answer, and that has been given. Besides the OP was really asking about the name of a commercial brand of fruit juice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Minute Maid<sup>®</sup> is a brand of frozen orange juice concentrate, from which an orange juice drink can be made by adding water.

From the Minute Maid<sup>®</sup> [web site](http://www.minutemaid.ca/en/inside_story/history.htm):

> From the city famous for its Minutemen militia, a Boston advertising
>   agency came up with the name “Minute Maid” reflecting the convenience
>   and ease of preparation.

Minute Maid<sup>®</sup> is a play on the words *“made in a minute”* or “[*in a*] *minute made*”.

Comment: Any relation of the maid in Nestle's Milkmaid?

Comment: @Kris Twins separated at birth...

Answer (score 2):

It could also mean “the little maid”. :)

*Minute* has many meanings and with different pronunciations, including:

- One minute (time). /ˈmɪnɪt/
- Insignificant, very small, slight etc. /mʌɪˈnjuːt/

Comment: Well, the OP didn't mention anything about the orange juice brand in the question, so without context a *minute maid* could indeed refer to a very small delicate female domestic servant or virgin! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a ***pun*** on the word ***"maid"*** and ***"made"***. It is such a beverage which can be ***'made in a minute'***. Particularly the word ***"maid"*** may have been used by taking a cue from *'milk maid'*.

Comment: practically the same answer as [Gnawme's](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/56339/44619)